# Access to save lists in the close as duplicate modal

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, duplicate-suggestions, saves

Now that we have the option to create multiple save lists, can we have the option to show the content of said lists in the "Close as duplicate" modal dialog?

I have a couple of questions saved there that I regularly use to close as a duplicate because the topics come up pretty often.

Example:

[image]

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/make-list-of-saved-questions-accessible-during-duplicate-dialogue I also posted the same question on academia SE meta.